# Custom Post Type Archive Page not showing

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a category on my website called 'profiles' I am in the process of moving this category to a custom post type called 'profiles'.

My problem is I cannot get the archive page to show for this custom post type. When I go to the url `mywebsite.com/profiles` it takes me to a single post page for a post in the profiles category.

I have included `has_archive = true;` in my `functions.php`

I didn't have a problem creating an archive page for another custom post type I did on the same website so Im really lost as to why this is not working this time.

Any advice would be most appreciated?

```
add_action( 'init', 'profile_custom_init' );

/* Here's how to create your customized labels */
function profile_custom_init() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Profiles', 'post type general name' ), // Tip: _x('') is used for localization
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Profile', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'Profile' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Profile' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Profile' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Profile' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Profile' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search Profile' ),
    'not_found' =>  __( 'No Profile found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Profile found in Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

// Create an array for the $args
$args = array( 'labels' => $labels, /* NOTICE: the $labels variable is used here... */
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 10,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
    ); 

    register_post_type( 'profile', $args ); /* Register it and move on */
}
```

Comment: Try changing profile category slug to something else like profiles-2.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. Also if I go to the url mywebsite.com/his for example instead of taking me to a 404 page (I dont have any page or post called just 'His') it takes me to a post beginning with the word 'his'. This seems very strange?

Comment: Have you tried to save your permalink structure again? This causes the rewrite rules to be regenerated.

Comment: Try re saving permalink structure by clicking on Save Changes button of Permalink Settings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Navigate to Settings -> permalinks
2. Change the permalink structure to *Default*
3. Save settings
4. Change to custom structure or post name (or any other structure)
5. Save Settings

This will re-write the htaccess file and then the re-write should work.

---

If the above solution doesn't work - it should be related to server configuration.

Aapache2

Run: `a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 reload`

Nginx

Follow: https://do.co/2LjCF8r

---

I hope this will save your time.

Comment: This solved it for me.

Comment: Classic flush_rewrite_rules, always forget about it :)

Comment: 1-5 worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Re saving the permalink structure seemed to fix the issue.
Thanks for the tip Mike and Vinod.

Comment: I answered this before Nikhil and thought it would be helpful. I hadn't checked back since he posted the better answer. So it's a bit unfair to accuse me of not giving the credit to the people who posted the answer.

Comment: my bad, I saw the march after october and thought it was the next year.. your sparse answer combined with that looked like a quick credit grab.. I should have looked more closely (sorting by number of votes doesn't help with quick looks either), gave you the up-vote on both question and answer

Comment: @Kender - I haven't had any intention to grab credits of someone else answer or copying it. I answered it as per my experience and I have explained the answer in a detailed manner. It may help lots of developers to fix the problem from the CMS side as well as the server.